# Initialise custom property when json property is serialised in android GSON?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit with gson , i have and getting FullName from server in JSON , now i want to add two `property` to this `Pojo class` , and i want to extact `firstName` and `lastName` of user . i am adding my logic in setter method of `FullName`
EX:

```
     public class MyPojo {

            @SerializedName("full_name")
            @Expose
            private String fullName;

            // property not in json
           String firstName;
           String lastName;

     public void setFullName(String fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;

    //**‼️** Here i want to add some logic and intialise first name and last name 

this.firstName = // Some value 
this.lastname = // some value

       }

    }
```

How can i initialize `firstName` and `lastName` when ever `fullName` initialised

Comment: Are you getting `full_name` from a response in your pojo `class`?

Comment: yes @RakeshKumar

Comment: If you are getting space or any special character `full_name` with then you can simply split it into `first` and `last` name

Comment: yeah , i have already that logic to split name but only my concern is how can i initialise `firstName` and `lastName` when `fullName` is initialised .
when i am placing code in `fullName` setter method , then `firstName` and `lastName` is `null`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to initialize these fields when DE-serializing from json?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in `getter` not `setter` as in

```
public class MyPojo {

            @SerializedName("full_name")
            @Expose
            private String fullName;

            // property not in json
           String firstName;
           String lastName;

           public String getFirstName(){
             this.firstName = "some value"; // can use fullName here
             return firstName;
           } 

           public String getLastName(){
             this.lastName = "some value"; // can use fullName here
             return lastName;
           } 

}
```

Comment: This pojo is also my room database entity , i can't do it in getting method , because  , once i get reponse form api i need to store in local room database .
 only possible way right now i am able to find is to  iterate thought all object From list and i have to update mannually , but i am only looking solution , how can i initialise those two property when fullName is initalised

Answer (score 0):

Try `JsonDeserializer`. Having a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MyPojo {
    private String fullName, firstName, lastName;
}
```

and JSON like:

```
{
    "fullName": "Firstname Lastname"
}
```

you could implement an adapter like:

```
public class MyPojoAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<MyPojo> {
    @Override
    public MyPojo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                                    JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        MyPojo n = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);
        String[] names = n.getFullName().split(" "); // or whatever your logic is
        n.setFirstName(names[0]);
        n.setLastName(names[1]);
        return n;
    }
}
```

Then before you register Gson with Retrofit you need to add:

```
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyPojo.class, new MyPojoAdapter());
```